# netty udp server with byteprocessor example

Tags: java, io, udp, netty, datagram

I have been trying to learn netty in my spare time and have come to a bit of a road block which I was hoping to get some help on. I am trying to create a simple program whereby a datagram packet is sent in hex format which is then displayed in the server console.

Server code

```
public final class UdpServer {

private static final int PORT = Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("port", "6565"));

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    try {
        Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
        b.group(group)
                .channel(NioDatagramChannel.class)
                .handler(new UdpServerHandler());

        b.bind(PORT).sync().channel().closeFuture().await();
    } finally {
        group.shutdownGracefully();
    }
}
```

}

Udp Server Handler

```
public class UdpServerHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<DatagramPacket> {

private ByteBuf buf;

@Override
public void handlerAdded(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
    buf = ctx.alloc().buffer(64);
}

@Override
public void handlerRemoved(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
    buf.release();
    buf = null;
}

@Override
public void channelRead0 (ChannelHandlerContext ctx, DatagramPacket packet) {
    System.out.println("UDP messaged received");
    buf=packet.content();
    buf.forEachByte(new ByteProcessor() {
    @Override
        public boolean process(Byte value) {
        System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(value));
        return false;
    }
    });
}

@Override
public void channelReadComplete(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
    ctx.flush();
}
```

}

So i watched Norman talk on youtube about netty best practices (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_GRIyCMNGGI at t=29:00) and tried to use the ByteProcessor method. Sadly, i couldnt find many example of this being used so I have struggled to get my code to work. I would like to point out I am a novice in java and still learning.

I would like to display the hex output in the console using system.out.println, is my approach correct or have I tried this from the wrong angle? your help would be much appreciated

Comment: did you solved this problem?

Comment: Sort of, I used bytebuf instead of byteprocessor. I did not need to use byteprocessor for what I wanted.